# does well in/with/?

Tags: word-choice

I am not sure how to connect "does well" with the rest of my sentence:

> The private sector **does well in terms of** offering people entertainment and without the competition propelled by public money there would be even more ways to spend this special night.

Could it be:

> The private sector **does well with** offering people entertainment...

Or something else?

Comment: Why do you want to change it from *in terms of*?

Comment: @JasonBassford Just wasn't sure if this is fine. If is I am happy with that